# What is a good tool to generate traffic stats for IIS 7.5?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

How can I know how many users are using a IIS server, and who are them (IP, etc)?
There is a tool for showing these kind of stats?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SmarterStats](http://www.smartertools.com/smarterstats/web-analytics-seo-software.aspx) is a great tool.  It's free for a single site, and very affordable for multiple sites.

For advanced troubleshooting Log Parser is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to loook at [IISView](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iisview/)

Comment: thanks! I'll take a look... (I didn't vote you up because I'm not able yet!)

Answer (score 1):

Current version of IISView is available at http://www.chapelhill.homeip.net/IISView/index.htm